# Como encontra erro de Fatal error: Out of memory wp-db.php

Tags: php, wordpress

O que sinigfica esse erro no wordpress e como arrumar isso

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 247988224) (tried to allocate 17584463 bytes) in /backup/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1094

Comment: Percebi que teve várias perguntas fechadas recentemente. Para aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta sugiro que leia o guia [ask] e faça um [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro não é especifico do Wordpress e sim do PHP, está estourando o limite de memória.

Você pode aumentar o limite da memória:

*Pelo código*

```
ini_set('memory_limit','QTDE_MEMORIA');
```

*Pelo php.ini*

```
memory_limit = QTDE_MEMORIA;
```

---

Neste [tutorial](http://wpmidia.com.br/tutoriais/4-formas-de-aumentar-limite-de-memoria-php-wordpress/), existe 4 formas de aumentar a memória do seu PHP.

Comment: Onde fica esse php.ini  ?  na pasta wordpress ?

Comment: Acho que o Wordpress não cria automaticamente, você pode seguir esse tutorial para aumentar o limite: http://wpmidia.com.br/tutoriais/4-formas-de-aumentar-limite-de-memoria-php-wordpress/